# bad input shape () LabelEncode?

Tags: python, data-science, machine-code

this is my code in jupyternotebook 
iam confused why do I'm getting a bad input shape error. The line that fails is in my code  is given below,by opening the dataset file and use for spliting The possible
output classes are higher than 50K or lower than or equal to 50K. There is a slight twist in this dataset in
the sense that each datapoint is a mixture of numbers and strings

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if '?' in line:
            continue
        data = line[:-1].split(', ')

        if data[-1] == '<=50K' and count_lessthan50k < num_images_threshold:
            X.append(data)
            count_lessthan50k = count_lessthan50k + 1
        elif data[-1] == '>50K' and count_morethan50k <
num_images_threshold:
            X.append(data)
            count_morethan50k = count_morethan50k + 1
        if count_lessthan50k >= num_images_threshold and count_morethan50k>= num_images_threshold:
            break
X = np.array(X)
```

this is for Convert string data to numerical data

```
label_encoder = []
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)

for i, item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:, i] = X[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(X[:,i])


X = X_encoded[:, :-1].astype(int)
y = X_encoded[:, -1].astype(int)
```

Cross validation the data

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,
                                                random_state=5)

classifier_gaussiannb = GaussianNB()
classifier_gaussiannb.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_test_pred = classifier_gaussiannb.predict(X_test)
```

Testing encoding on single data instance

```
input_data = ['39', 'State-gov', '77516', 'Bachelors', '13','Never-married', 'Adm-clerical', 'Not-in-family', 'White','Male', '2174', '0', '40', 'United-States']



count = 0
input_data_encoded = [-1] * len(input_data)

for i,item in enumerate(input_data):
    if item.isdigit():
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(input_data[i])
    else:
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(input_data[i]))
        count = count + 1

input_data_encoded = np.array(input_data_encoded)
```

i have gone through the sklearn documentation but did not work for me, any help ??

Answer (score 0):

LabelEncoder `transform()` requires an iterable of all the samples at once to transform as mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.transform):-

> ```
> Transform labels to normalized encoding.
>
> Parameters     y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
>                Target values.
> ```

If you want to pass a single value each time to it, you need to wrap it inside a list like this:

```
else:
    input_data_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform([input_data[i]]))
```

Notice the extra square brackets around the `input_data[i]`.